# Calculation Correlation Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to calculate the correlation time. First I calculate the auto-correlation function:

$$
\begin{align}
\chi(t) = &\frac{1}{t_{max}-t}\sum\limits_{t'=0}^{t_{max}-t}m(t')m(t'+t)\\
&-\frac{1}{t_{max}-t}\sum\limits_{t'=0}^{t_{max}-t}m(t')\frac{1}{t_{max}-t}\sum\limits_{t'=0}^{t_{max}-t}m(t'+t)\\
&\sim e^{-t/\tau}
\end{align}
$$

The correlation-time can be calculated by fitting autocorrelation function. I.e., \$\chi(t)\$ in exponential.
For this I have written the following code:

```
def autocorrelation(M):
    start_time = time.time()
    tau = 1
    sweeps = len(M)
    auto = np.zeros(sweeps)
    for t in range(sweeps):
        some_time = sweeps-t
        first_term = np.average(M[:some_time]*M[t:sweeps])
        S1 = np.average(M[:some_time])
        S2 = np.average(M[t:sweeps])
        auto_temp = first_term - S1*S2
        if auto_temp > 0:
            auto[t] = auto_temp
        else:#remove oscillating part
            break 
    if auto[0] != 0:
        auto = auto[auto>0]
        auto = auto/auto[0] #normalization
        len_auto = len(auto)
        if len_auto > 1: #draw a straight line if you have atleast two points
            tau = int(-1/np.polyfit(np.arange(len_auto), np.log(auto), 1, w=np.sqrt(auto))[0])
    tau = max(tau,1)
    logging.info(f"Correlation time = {tau}")
    return tau
```

If you put in list `M = m`, the function will calculate autocorrelation function and return correlation time, i.e, \$\tau\$ I also thought of using NumPy's `correlate` and `convolve`, but I could not understand them well. I tried `auto_convolve = numpy.convolve(m,m,mode = "same")`, after normalization, the `auto/auto[0]` was not same as `auto_convolve/auto_convolve[0]`

Comment: Please can you check the equation. Why do you have \$\frac{1}{t_{max}-t}\$ twice in the second line of the equation and not just simplify to \$\frac{1}{(t_{max}-t)^2}\$. Additionally please use parentheses in situations like the above it's unclear what is inside the Sigma, is that a nested Sigma?

Comment: It's because there are two averages in the second term. I tried putting parenthesis, but it showed error: `Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.`

Comment: The second term in expression of \$\chi(t)\$ is \$\bigg(\frac{1}{t_{max}-t}\sum\limits_{t'=0}^{t_{max}-t}m(t')\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{t_{max}-t}\sum\limits_{t'=0}^{t_{max}-t}m(t'+t)\bigg)\$.